# GeoTools: how to get Bursa-Wolf parameters from GeodeticDatum instance

Tags: java, geotools

I have an instance of type `GeodeticDatum`. I can get ellipsoid name, flattening, axes using methods `datum.getEllipsoid()` and `getName()`, `getInverseFlattening()`, etc.

How can I get Bursa-Wolf parameters (towgs84) without converting datum to WKT string and parsing it manually?

```
DATUM["New Zealand Geodetic Datum 1949", 
  SPHEROID["International 1924", 6378388.0, 297.0], 
  TOWGS84[59.47, -5.04, 187.44, 0.47, -0.1, 1.024, -4.5993]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ProjectedCRS crsFromWkt = (ProjectedCRS) CRS.parseWKT(/*OGC WKT of your projected coordinate system*/):
DefaultGeodeticDatum defaultGeodeticDatum = new DefaultGeodeticDatum(crsFromWkt.getDatum());
        System.out.println(defaultGeodeticDatum.getBursaWolfParameters()[0].dx);
        System.out.println(defaultGeodeticDatum.getBursaWolfParameters()[0].dy);
        System.out.println(defaultGeodeticDatum.getBursaWolfParameters()[0].dz);
        System.out.println(defaultGeodeticDatum.getBursaWolfParameters()[0].ex);
        System.out.println(defaultGeodeticDatum.getBursaWolfParameters()[0].ey);
        System.out.println(defaultGeodeticDatum.getBursaWolfParameters()[0].ez);
        System.out.println(defaultGeodeticDatum.getBursaWolfParameters()[0].ppm);
```

Comment: What's the definition of `crsFromWkt`?

Comment: Thank you for spotting this. The answer's been amended.